# Spring Controller not called when typing JSP file extension in URL

Tags: spring, jsp, url, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring MVC and Spring Security 3.

My problem is, that if I call the servlet like www.mydomain.com/**app.do** everything works fine, means the controller gets called. But if call www.mydomain.com/**app.jsp** the controller does not get invoked. Same is for **login.do** servlet and **login.jsp** file.

The physical file **app.jsp** is located within the root **/** directory.

Is this the expected behavior of Spring MVC? Can I somehow force that spring mvc does also process the JSP file? Or even forbid to call the URL? How is this usually handled?

**web.xml**

```
...
    <!-- Spring Security filter mapping -->   
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 

    <!-- Spring MVC servlet mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
...
```

**spring-mvc-servlet.xml**

```
...
    <context:component-scan base-package="ch.hobus.metronom.server" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
...
```

**spring-security-xml**

```
...
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/app*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/metronom/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/gwt/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.do" 
                    default-target-url="/app.do"
                    authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.do" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout.do" />
</http>
...
```

**LoginController.java**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/login.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String login(ModelMap model) {
    return "login";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "login";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/logout.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String logout(ModelMap model) {
    return "login";
  }

}
```

**AppController.java**

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/app.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView app(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("app");
    mav.addObject("username", principal.getName());
    mav.addObject("message", "Metronom's benutzerdefiniertes Formular");
    return mav;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's expected behavior. If you ask for a JSP, you get a JSP. The solutions:

- don't include any link to any JSP in the web app
- store the JSPs under /WEB-INF
- map the Spring servlet to `/*` (but then it will also be invoked for images, CSS files, etc. You'll have to use [mvc:resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-config-static-resources) to handle this situation).